# What photon energy is needed to photodissociate large elements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, nuclear-physics, supernova

During core collapse, the heat and pressure produces photons with energy levels that photodissociate iron. I was wondering what photon energy is required to do such a thing?

Comment: More on photodissociation: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36725/16685 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36758/16685 (also by ProfRob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the difference in binding energies between a $^{56}$Fe nucleus and the sum of binding energies for an alpha particle and $^{52}$Cr. It is 7.61 MeV.

The difference between the binding energies of $^{56}$Ni and an alpha particle plus $^{52}$Fe is 8.0 MeV.

Thus you need photons of around 8 MeV to knock an alpha particle out of an iron-peak nucleus and begin the process of photo-disintegration.

Roughly speaking, you have a population of such photons once temperatures reach $k_B T\sim 1$ MeV, since the average photon energy in the Planck distribution is $2.8 k_BT$ and there will be a high energy tail extending beyond 8 MeV.

Note added: to knock off a single neutron or proton would take photons with slightly higher energy (10-11 MeV), so it is alpha particles that are produced first. The ejection (or fission) of nuclei larger than alpha particles would take much more energy because iron/nickel are at the peak of the binding energy per nucleon curve.

Comment: Just to check the terminology, is this more properly called photofission than photodissasociation?

Comment: @LeeMosher Photofission sounds to me like photon-induced fission into two roughly equal pieces. This (correct) answer gives the "nucleon separation energies," which hover around 8–10 MeV for most stable-ish isotopes. So in an MeV thermal bath, heavy nuclei will shed nucleons singly or in clusters.

Comment: Oh hey professor! Thanks for answering :)